# Ajax sparql query 400 bad request error

Tags: jquery, ajax, sparql

I tried to send a sparql query by ajax, but there is an error.

First, this code works correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
img {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
var query = "\
  PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>\
  PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\
  SELECT DISTINCT *\
  WHERE {\
      ?s dbpedia2:genus \"Apis\"@en; \
       foaf:depiction ?o\
  }";
var queryUrl = encodeURI( url+"?query="+query+"&format=json" );

$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: queryUrl,
    success: function( _data ) {
        var vars = _data.head.vars;
        var result = _data.results.bindings;
               $('body').append('<table></table>');
                           var table = $('table');
                          $('table').append('<tr><th>?s</th><th>?o</th></tr>');
                           var str = "<tr>";
                           for(var i = 2; i < vars.length; i++)
                           {
                                   str += '<th>'+vars[i].value+'</th>';
                                   alert(str);
                           }

                           str += "</tr>";

                           table.append(str);

                           str = "";
                           for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                           {
                                   str += "<tr>";

                                   for(var j = 0; j < vars.length; j++)
                                   {
                                           if(result[i].hasOwnProperty(vars[j])) str += '<td>'+result[i][vars[j]]['value']+'</td>';
                                           else str += '<td></td>';
                                   }

                                   str += "</tr>";
                           }

                           table.append(str);
      //  }
    },

});
</script>
</html>
```

After changing the query part, it does not work.

```
var query = "\
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>\
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \
SELECT ?s ?slabel ?o\
WHERE {\
    ?s dbpedia2:genus \"Apis\"@en;\
       rdfs:label ?slabel\
       foaf:depiction ?o\
}";
```

Can you tell me the reason of that bad request error?
Thank you!

Comment: This is too obvious, print the query and you should see it. You have a **missing semicolon** in your query after `rdfs:label ?sLabel` -> `rdfs:label ?sLabel ;` . Multiple triple patterns in SPARQL group graph pattern have too be separated by dot `.` (resp. `;` and `,` for the Turtle conciseness feature).

Comment: By the way, it's always a good way to run the printed query directly in a Web UI of the triple store (if exists).

Comment: Thank you for your help @AKSW, but it does not work, too. I changed query like this.
`var query = "\
      PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>\
      PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\
      PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \
      SELECT ?s ?slabel ?o\
      WHERE {\
          ?s dbpedia2:genus ?o1. \
          ?s rdfs:label ?slabel. \
          ?s foaf:depiction ?o2.\
          FILTER regex(str(?o1), \"Apis\")\
          FILTER (lang(?o1)=\"en\")\
      }";`

Comment: And I check the query as alert(); it shows that like this.

`PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>      PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>      PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>       SELECT ?s ?slabel ?o      WHERE {          ?s dbpedia2:genus ?o1.           ?s rdfs:label ?slabel.           ?s foaf:depiction ?o2.          FILTER regex(str(?o1), "Apis")          FILTER (lang(?o1)="en")      }`

Comment: Now the error is `Variable 'o' is used in the query result set but not assigned`.

Comment: @LydiaYoo You're showing now a totally different query! StanislavKralin is right. It looks like you did not understand SPARQL and simply edited a query from somewhere else. You have to `SELECT` the variables that you want! And as I said, if you run this query in the DBpedia WebUI, you would get the error that StanislavKralin has shown - which should be enough to understand the problem and solve it by yourself.

Comment: @AKSW, Stanislav Kralin I need to try it dbpedia sparql endpoint before modifying query in html source code, . Thanks a lot!

Comment: No need to try if you make it correctly in the source code. But at least it's a better way to debug the query as you get usually a hint on what's going wrong.